# Deadlock while using ReadFile and WriteFile

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm working on a school project where I'm trying to show at the StdOut of a child process what was written in the StdIn of the parent; and vice-versa, i.e, show what was written on the child process StdIn on the parent StdOut but I reached a deadlock with the ReadFile and WriteFile operations.

From what i could gather during research on this topic this is an usual problem while using synchronous pipes.

Should the read and write on the pipes operation be synchronized by an event?
Do you suggest other approach?
Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
Parent.cpp

   #include <windows.h>
   #include <iostream>
   #include <stdio.h>

   //read handle pipe1
   HANDLE r1 = NULL;

   //write handle pip1
   HANDLE w1 = NULL;

   //read handle pipe2
   HANDLE r2 = NULL;

   //write handle for pipe2
   HANDLE w2 = NULL;

   #define BUFSIZE 4096

   void CreateChildProcess() {
       TCHAR applicationName[] = TEXT("Child");
       PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
       STARTUPINFO si;
       BOOL success = FALSE;

       ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
       ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));

       si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
       si.hStdError = w1;
       si.hStdOutput = w1;
       si.hStdInput = r2;
       si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;


       success = CreateProcess(NULL, applicationName, NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);

       if (!success) {
           printf("Error creating child process \n");
       }
       else {

           printf("Child process successfuly created \n");
           CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
           CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
       }
   }
   void WriteToPipe() {
       DWORD read, written;
       CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE];
       BOOL success = FALSE;

       HANDLE pStdIn = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

       for (;;)
       {
           success = ReadFile(pStdIn, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &read, NULL);
           if (!success || read == 0) break;

           success = WriteFile(w2, chBuf, read, &written, NULL);
           if (!success) break;
       }
   }

   void ReadFromPipe() {
       DWORD read, written;
       CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE];
       BOOL success = FALSE;

       HANDLE pStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

       for (;;)
       {
           success = ReadFile(r1, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &read, NULL);
           if (!success || read == 0) break;

           success = WriteFile(pStdOut, chBuf, read, &written, NULL);
           if (!success) break;
       }
   }

   int main()
   {

       DWORD dRead, dWritten;
       CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE];
       BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;

       SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttr;
       secAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
       secAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
       secAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

       printf("Creating first pipe\n");
       if (!CreatePipe(&r1, &w1, &secAttr, 0)) {
           printf("\nError creating first pipe\n");
       }
       printf("Creating second pipe\n");
       if (!CreatePipe(&r2, &w2, &secAttr, 0)) {
           printf("Error creating second pipe \n");
       }


       if (!SetHandleInformation(r1, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0)) {
           printf("r1 SetHandleInformation \n");
       }
       if (!SetHandleInformation(w2, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0)) {
           printf("w2 SetHandleInformation \n");
       }


       printf("\nCreating child process..... \n");
       CreateChildProcess();

       WriteToPipe();
       ReadFromPipe();

       return 0;
   }

Child.cpp

   #include <windows.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include "pch.h"

   #define BUFSIZE 4096

   int main()
   {
       DWORD dRead, dWritten;
       CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE];
       BOOL success = FALSE;
       HANDLE stdIn = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
       HANDLE stdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);


       if (stdIn == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE || stdOut == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
           ExitProcess(1);
       }

       for (;;) {
           success = ReadFile(stdIn, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dRead, NULL);
           if (!success || dRead == 0) break;
success = WriteFile(stdOut, chBuf, dRead, &dWritten, NULL);
           if (!success) break;
       }

       return 0;
   }
```

Comment: At what points exactly do your processes stop? What did you observe? Why do you think it's a deadlock?

Comment: You never close pipe handles. Also parent process seem to read and write through std input output for no reason.

Comment: of course you got deadlock here, because use synchronous io and both processes begin from ReadFile. use asynchronous io and only **single** pipe paire.

Comment: Press the "break" button in the debugger and examine the call stack to see where the deadlock happens in your code.

Comment: @zett42 - in concrete case this is obvious even just - in call `ReadFile` - this synchronous call (if all parameters correct) not return until data will be not written to pipe. but both processes begin from `ReadFile`.

Comment: @RbMm It is certainly not obvious for OP, otherwise this question wouldn't exist. I'm trying to help OP to self diagnose such issues using a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You will not able to show what was written on the child process StdIn on the parent StdOut, since the child's stdIn Handle was set to "r2". So that you are not able to insert anything in child process manually. I suggest to use [namepipe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ipc/named-pipe-server-using-overlapped-i-o), so that child's std handle will not mix with other pipe handles.

for(;;) is equal to while(1), and ReadFile() won't return until receive the data, so if there no exception(exclude no data incoming) occurs, the loop will never break, and the code won't go ahead to ReadFromPipe();

Use the Overlap mode of namepipe Or Try to create 2 threads and 2 namepipes, one to read from namepipe then print out and the other to read from stdin then write to namepipe(in both processes).